# There was an error while getting the sharing information

Tags: grub2, gnome, usb, sudo, backup

I’m taking backup by Ubuntu 2.02
And it’s done. But when I open this folder’s properties then a notification appears.
Notification is  given below:
There was an error while getting the sharing information.

```
Failed to execute child process ”net” (No such a file or directory)
```

But the directory exists and This notification can not erase.

I want to ask why this error appears and how should I solve it?
I’m bigger on it.

Comment: Please clarify your release, 2.02 means the 2002-February release? of which there is none. Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format (excluding specialist releases which are *year* only but refer to a different product) so your details are incorrect, or you're not using Ubuntu at all.

Comment: Actually I don’t know briefly but I’m using Ubuntu installed USB 3.0 flash memory..And on its display it’s showing  install Ubuntu 19.10  …when I opened Ubuntu it shows GNU GRUB version 2.02  I don’t know what it mean.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: `grub` is a GNU bootloader, and is a key boot loader used by Ubuntu as well as many other OSes (it's also not the only one used by Ubuntu depending on release; though it's preferred).  It's not specifically part of Ubuntu, but is used when you have two OSes involved so you can select which you want to boot. If grub rescue appears, that's usually because part of it has been damaged & only stage 0 appears (which is isn't enough to boot; it's the MBR that boots later stages & provides limited rescue functionality if it can't run later stages).  You're off-topic though here now though

Comment: Thank you for your support